# Any checklist/guide when transferring a database to a new server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005

I'm looking for steps that I need to follow to transfer a database to a new server.  So far I have:

1. I restored the current database that I have in SQL Server 2005 instance to another SQL Server 2008R2 from backups
2. Transferred all the database and security logins, Linked server
3. Re-created the SQL Server agent jobs (including an SSIS package) and maintenance plans
4. Expanding all the other Objects in SSMS but nothing else to move
5. Planning to choose the database task: "Take-Offline" instead of "Detach", not sure why!
6. Point an existing application (built on VB)to the new server, and hopefully it will run the reports (thats calling my SQL stored procedures) successfully!

So am I missing anything else that I should transfer?

Comment: The difference between OFFLINE and Detach is that OFFLINE leaves the database in a state visible (but not usable) to the SQL instance.  Detach removes it from the instance (but does not delete the files).

Comment: You can have a look at my answer [**Upgrade SQL Server 2000 database to 2008 R2 and enable new features**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783). Those are general guidelines but covers majority of points including post restore tasks.

Comment: @MikeFal Thank you for your advice, in my case then I think either way will bo ok, right? as they will get rid of the old server that has the SQL server 2005 instance and we will keep the new server that has the upgraded SQL Server 2008r2 instance. Thanks.

Comment: @Kin Very useful guidelines, thanks for pointing that to me. I will check it for sure, as it may be very similar to to upgrading from SQL Server 2005 instead of 2000 to SQL Server 2008r2.