# SQL Server 2008 upgrade and clean

Tags: sql-server, ssms, upgrade

After upgrading a SQL Server 2008 instance to SQL Server 2012 (in-place upgrade), there appears to be numerous 2008 instance components (namely the 2008 SSMS in start menu, in add/remove programs Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and other items in add/remove programs relating to SQL Server 2008).

How to remove all traces of SQL Server 2008 such that the database is a clean 2012 instance?

Comment: You can remove the older components related to sql 2008 from the add/remove program. Ideally, I would prefer a side by side migration - installing sql 2012 and then performing backup/restore of 2008 databases to 2012. Also, refer to [post upgrade steps](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783).

Comment: Thanks Kin but the application requires use of the default instance, and my understanding is that the instance cannot be changed after install. Unless there is another way around this?