# SQL Server 2005 Whole-Migration, which databases should I recreate?

Tags: sql-server-2005, migration, system-tables, system-databases

In relation to [my question about SQL Server 2005 migration procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61083/procedure-to-wholly-migrate-sql-server-2005-to-a-new-server), I am re-creating the databases on the new server.

I noted that the old server has the following databases (outside of System Databases):

```
 1. Analysis Server Repository
 2. Archive
 3. BCI
 4. BDD Data Center
 5. Nemo
 6. Fixing
 7. Neutron
 8. ReportServer
 9. ReportServerTempDB
10. Sharepoint
11. STS_ho_whdata_1
12. TVS
```

Now, some of the databases are clearly custom-made, e.g., #5, #6, #7, #11, etc. However there are some databases that -- from their name -- doesn't seem like databases created by the (previous) dev/maintainer, e.g., #1 and #8.

Is it safe for me to re-create all databases willy-nilly, and just 'copy' the data from the old server to the new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really care to know which databases are in use, you have to use dmv's (log that data to a table as they get flushed out when server is restarted) or profiler (server side trace) and just filter out the logins and program names connecting to those databases.

once you have that info for your complete business cycle, you will be able to figure out what databases needs to be moved to new server.

also, backup/restore should be a preferred method unless you have a reason of not doing it.

note: we do not know your environment, nor your business so we CANNOT answer what databases you need to move.

reportserver* are eelayed to reporting server that might be installed on the current server.

Comment: I hope I wasn't being unclear; I'm not trying to reduce the number of databases being migrated. I just want to make sure that if I re-created all databases (except `ReportServer` and `ReportServerTempDB`, which apparently were created automatically by SQL Server), it will not conflict any SQL Server services.

Comment: No it wont affect any sql services.