# Migrate sharepoint database from SQL Server 2012 express to SQL Server 2012 Standard

Tags: sql-server-2012, sharepoint

My sharepoint is using SQL Server 2012 R2 Express as a database Server, and I already have reached the limit of space (10GB). In the other hand I have a SQL Server 2012 Standard with proper license.

1. Would it be possible to migrate my database to SQL Server Std?
2. Can I install my SQL Server 2012 Std on the same server I have of my SQL Server Express?
3. Is there any risk doing that in terms of sharepoint compatibility?

> NOTE: I have installed SQL Server 2012 Std on same server but the db size limit still persist, is this normal?

Comment: On your note might ensure there is no quota limit or restriction on the SharePoint side...Are you getting error messages in SQL Log that indicate on instance side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be possible to migrate my database to SQL Server Std?

Yes, a backup and restore approach would work for this situation. For a detailed migration steps (ignoring the ones that you dont need - as it is for migrating from lower to higher version), [refer to this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783).

> Can I install my SQL Server 2012 Std on the same server I have of my SQL Server Express?

Yes, Express and standard editions can co-exists together. Make sure that your server have enough memory, CPU and disk space. Also, make sure to cap the Max memory setting on the instances appropriately.

> Is there any risk doing that in terms of sharepoint compatibility?

We have SharePoint running in our environment on SQL server 2012 standard edition, so I dont see any issues. What risks are you referring to ?

> NOTE: I have installed SQL Server 2012 Std on same server but the db size limit still persist, is this normal?

No that is not normal.  See Database size [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Below script will give you more detailed info about the version you are running :

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.],
 SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation') AS Collation
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are some good links from Microsoft which tell you how to move databases specially content database of Sharepoint server. You can select appropriate sharepoint version.

[Move all databases in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx)

[Move content databases in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792(v=office.15).aspx)

> NOTE: I have installed SQL Server 2012 Std on same server but the db size limit still persist, is this normal?

No this is not possible SQL server 2012 Standard edition database has no such Limit of 10 G database restriction. Can you check autogrowth setting make sure you have not put limit on autogrowth for data and log files.