# Converting a SQL Server 2000 Database to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I need to restore a SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2016. Is there any possible way to do this without having to install a complete copy of SQL Server 2008, restore to 2008, change the compatibility level and then restore the 2008 backup to 2016? I know this would work but I really don't want to install 2008 R2 just for this single purpose unless I have no other choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is **NOT** possible to restore a SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2016 without restoring it to 2008 R2 first.

Here is an answer by [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) with details on alternate options to get the data out of the SQL 2000 database https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99340/60898.

Answer (score 6):

*Adding more info and complementing @sql_handle's answer ...*

[You can upgrade from any version 2005+ to any other version](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/you-can-upgrade-from-any-version-2005-to-any-other-version/).

Since you are on SQL 2000, you have to have a jump server to facilitate the upgrade to sql server 2016.

Also, entire migration can be automated using [dbatools - PowerShell script - `start-sqlmigration`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Start-DbaMigration).

I have answered [Upgrade SQL Server 2000 database..](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783) with steps and best practices which will be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to restore your data from SQL 2000 to SQL 2016 directly but you can import it from SQL 2000 to SQL 2016.

Here is how I import the data, just follow the steps below.

Step 1. Right click in any table then choose Import data

[image]

Step 2. Click Next after DTS Import/Export Wizard appeared

[image]

Step 3. Choose your Data Source **(SQL 2000)**

[image]

Step 4. Choose your destination **(SQL 2016)**, You need to create DSN connection (ODBC connection) to connect to SQL 2016

[image]

Step 5. Select all tables

[image]

Step 6. Choose copy tables and views from the source database

[image]

Step 7. Select Run immediately

Step 8. Click Finish

Step 9. Process import data to SQL 2016, this process will take a minute, it depends on how many data do you have. Just relax and wait.

[image]

Step 10. Finish

[image]