# SQL Server 2008 R2 version needed

Tags: sql-server, installation

Does any one have SQL server 2008 version?
I couldn't find it anywhere on microsoft website, because it's not supporting it anymore.
I need to migrate 2000 sql server to V19. For this I need intermediate version which is 2008 R2.
It's not even available on MSDN account.
If someone could guid me, it would be great!

thanks so much in advance

Comment: First link on Google https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30438 and SP4 is here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44278 and see also https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2008/01/sql-server-2008-versions.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But, The express edition has a limitation on database size of 1 GB. The 2000 server data still gets data everyday and its larger in size.
The only solution is to install 2008 R2 version and restore 2000 db to this unfortunately

Comment: So which edition do you need? Do note that 2008 is way out of date and unsupported now.

Comment: I need 2008 r2 version if someone has the file already. I need to use it to restore the 2000 version database to version 19

Comment: another option is to [import/export the data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218797/214884)

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying that as well. But the format data in 2000 version, is not copmpatible with 19 version. There are always data conversion or truncation errors when use their table meta data schema to create tables in new server. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Consider highlighting the truncation/conversion challenges you faced. If you've previously tried to address them, detail the steps you took within your question. Providing more specifics will enable others to help you more effectively.