# Move live SQL Server database to a new server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, migration, replication

I have a production server running SQL Server 2008 Web Edition, and it has to keep running 24x7 with almost no down time, and it's the time for us to move to a more advanced server hardware, also it's a good chance to move to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise.

Now my question, how can I do this migration without taking the database down at all? Like for example setting something between the two servers as replication or so, so I have exactly identical database up-to-second on both servers, then I can just take the main services down for 1 minute, changing the IP address of the database connection from old server to new server and I be sure that the new server has identical copy of the old one.

I can't go with backup/restore approach as it will take time more than acceptable period, that's why I need something which guarantee identical databases exactly as if I am doing backup/restore. 5 minutes could be the max affordable downtime.

The database size is about 100GB.

New server is running 2012 Enterprise, and old server is running 2008 Web

I can exceptionally archive records from the database and minimize its size down to 20GB like.

I have the option to upgrade my SQL Server 2008 Web edition to Enterprise edition if this will help with more solutions, like replication maybe?

Comment: @Abed you realize that upgrading from web to **enterprise** will incur a **downtime** and as per your question `it has to keep running 24x7 with almost no down time` ? If you go for enterprise, then I would suggest you go for mirroring (first async) and then during the switchover, switch the mirroring to SYNC. This will give you **minimum** downtime.

Answer (score 11):

since you are using SQL Server 2008 Web edition, your best bet is to use **`LOG SHIPPING`**.

Your database size is 100GB, so initializing the secondary from a backup should be considered. Dont use GUI to set up initial logshipping.

SO your steps should be :

- Backup 2008 Web edition database and restore it on 2012 enterprise `WITH NORECOVERY`.
- Launch Logshipping wizard and make sure to select `secondary is already initialized`. Configure logshipping to be every `1 min`(this is the minimum you can get).

  [image]
- Move all the logins, Jobs, SSIS packages.

**During the switch to new server :**

- stop all the webservers connecting to the database
- stop all the backup, copy and restore jobs of logshipping.
- take a final Tail log backup and restore it on secondary `WITH RECOVERY`.
- Sync the logins.
- Change the `web.config` of the application to point it to the new server. This way you dont have to change the IP address of the new server to match the old one.

I have given the [**post restore steps in more detailed manner here**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783).

Comment: the database has to move from Holland DC to Houston DC, quite long trip. the database is processing more than 5000 transaction per minute, all are billing and financials. a combination of thousands of update and insert commands per minute. I need something with zero tolerance, it's a disaster if the new server had any tiny issue with log file shipping.

Comment: @Abed you dont have any other options and IMHO logshipping when configured correctly (hard to get it wrong !) and running for few days will ensure and give you a confidence. Test it on a test server with a smaller database and once you are confident implement and replay the same on PROD.