# How to update statistics for a database's system tables

Tags: execution-plan, statistics, sql-server-2016

We recently upgraded many of our instances to 2016. As a result, a SELECT statement from [sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) is timing out on some instances.

After some testing, I found that by updating the statistics on the database's system tables showing up in the execution plan, the SELECT stopped timing out.

```
update statistics sys.[sysclsobjs] with fullscan
update statistics sys.[syscolpars] with fullscan
update statistics sys.[sysidxstats] with fullscan
update statistics sys.[sysiscols] with fullscan
update statistics sys.[sysobjvalues] with fullscan
```

Is there anyway either through the standard maintenance packages, Ola Hallengren's scripts or some other process to only update system table statistics?

**Update 08/01**

Here are the steps I took after upgrade

About the 4199 traceflag [KB974006](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974006)

```
-- for the instance
/* 
Turn on traceflag 4199 (my understanding of this traceflag is that it disables
optimizer hotfixes in 2016
*/

-- disable automatic numa
sp_configure 'automatic soft-NUMA disabled', 1
GO

-- For each database
-- Turn on Query optimizer hotfixes
-- Turn off Legacy cardinality estimation

exec sp_MSforeachDB 'ALTER DATABASE [?] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;
USE [?]; 
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = ON;
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = OFF;

-- update statistics for all tables, system tables are ignored
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable ''UPDATE STATISTICS [?] WITH FULLSCAN''
'
```

**Update 08/02**

Here is the SELECT from sqlpackage.exe causing timeouts for TFS

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
SCHEMA_NAME([o].[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName],
[si].[object_id] AS [ColumnSourceId],
[o].[name] AS [ColumnSourceName],
[o].[type] AS [ColumnSourceType],
[ic].[column_id] AS [ColumnId],
[c].[name] AS [ColumnName],
[si].[index_id] AS [IndexId],
[si].[name] AS [IndexName],
[ds].[type] AS [DataspaceType],
[ds].[data_space_id] AS [DataspaceId],
[ds].[name] AS [DataspaceName],
[si].[fill_factor] AS [FillFactor],
[si].[is_padded] AS [IsPadded],
[si].[is_disabled] AS [IsDisabled],
[si].[allow_page_locks] AS [DoAllowPageLocks],
[si].[allow_row_locks] AS [DoAllowRowLocks],
[sit].[cells_per_object] AS [CellsPerObject],
[sit].[bounding_box_xmin] AS [XMin],
[sit].[bounding_box_xmax] AS [XMax],
[sit].[bounding_box_ymin] AS [YMin],
[sit].[bounding_box_ymax] AS [YMax],
[sit].[level_1_grid] AS [Level1Grid],
[sit].[level_2_grid] AS [Level2Grid],
[sit].[level_3_grid] AS [Level3Grid],
[sit].[level_4_grid] AS [Level4Grid],
[sit].[tessellation_scheme] AS [TessellationScheme],
[s].[no_recompute] AS [NoRecomputeStatistics],
[p].[data_compression] AS [DataCompressionId],
CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN [ti].[data_space_id] = [ds].[data_space_id] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
AS [EqualsParentDataSpace]
FROM
[sys].[spatial_indexes] AS [si] WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] AS [o] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [o].[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[spatial_index_tessellations] [sit] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [sit].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [sit].[index_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[data_spaces] AS [ds] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [ds].[data_space_id] = [si].[data_space_id] 
INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] AS [ic] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [ic].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [ic].[index_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] AS [c] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [c].[object_id] AND [ic].[column_id] = [c].[column_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] AS [o2] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o2].[parent_object_id] = [si].[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[stats] AS [s] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o2].[object_id] = [s].[object_id] AND [s].[name] = [si].[name]
INNER JOIN [sys].[partitions] AS [p] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [p].[object_id] = [o2].[object_id] AND [p].[partition_number] = 1
LEFT JOIN [sys].[indexes] AS [ti] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o].[object_id] = [ti].[object_id]
LEFT JOIN [sys].[tables] AS [t] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [t].[object_id] = [si].[object_id]
WHERE [si].[is_hypothetical] = 0
AND [ti].[index_id] < 2
AND OBJECTPROPERTY([o].[object_id], N'IsSystemTable') = 0
AND ([t].[is_filetable] = 0 OR [t].[is_filetable] IS NULL)
AND ([o].[is_ms_shipped] = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM [sys].[extended_properties]
WHERE [major_id] = [o].[object_id]
AND [minor_id] = 0
AND [class] = 1
AND [name] = N'microsoft_database_tools_support'
))
) AS [_results]
```

If I don't update system table statistics for the database, then this SELECT can and will timeout when deploying via sqlpackage.exe

Comment: Do you have Auto Update Statistics enabled?

Comment: Hello @Peter, yes they are enabled on all of our databases.

Comment: is there a compelling reason to update stats on your system tables?

Comment: Hello @swasheck, yes there is. In the question, the reason to update system table statistics was due to a timeout error with the SELECT coming from the sqlpackage.exe binary. Without update statistics for the system tables in the execution plan, it takes 2 to 10 minutes for that SELECT to complete. Perhaps I should add the SELECT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "see" the system tables without using DAC connection:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.type = 'S'
ORDER BY o.name
```

From there, you could build a TSQL string of commands and execute it. (I hardcoded `sys` for the schema. Presumably this will never change.):

```
DECLARE @TSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @TSql = @TSql +  'UPDATE STATISTICS sys.' + o.name + ' WITH FULLSCAN;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.type = 'S'
ORDER BY o.name

--Verify/test commands.
PRINT @TSql

--Uncomment and re-run when ready to proceed.
--EXEC sp_executesql @TSql
```

This could easily be put into a job step for a SQL Agent job.  I tested this on SQL Server 2012 w/ SP3.  I've also run similar code in SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2014.  I don't know for sure if it works in SQL 2016--please let us know if it does not.

**Other Notes**
The `UPDATE STATISTICS` commands worked when I was logged in as a [sysadmin]. It also worked if the login was not a member of [sysadmin], but was the database owner.  Membership in [db_owner] alone was not sufficient.  (Again, this was on SQL 2012 w/ SP3. YMMV.)

Comment: As far as I can tell (meaning, I also tested on 2012 as I don't yet have 2016 installed) this answer is entirely correct. I verified the `Updated` stats date via both [DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx) and [STATS_DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190330.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[Ola's index maintenance script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) has parameter `SYSTEM_DATABASES` --> `All system databases (master, msdb, and model)` for `UpdateStatistics` --> `ALL - Update index and column statistics.` that takes care of updating stats for system databases as well.

Also, refer to [Statistics on system tables and query performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2011/06/29/statistics-on-system-tables-and-query-performance/). I have seen it very rare to update stats on system tables unless you have very large amount of objects in them (I still use Ola's script for weekly index maint on system tables).

As a side note: since you upgraded to SQL Server 2016, are you using the new CE ? What is the compatibility mode ?, were the [post upgrade steps done](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783) ?.

EDIT:

---

[Automatic soft NUMA is beneficial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/03/30/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-automatic-soft-numa/) - 30% gain in query performance was obtained by using Soft NUMA & [proper MAX DOP setting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36578/8783).

A small note : Please dont use undocumented `sp_MSforeachDB`. May be a dynamic sql is a much better option.

e.g.

```
select 'ALTER DATABASE '+quotename(name)+' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;'
     from sys.databases where database_id > 4 and state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

If you are consistently seeing the behaviour of those system base tables getting out dated, then you should file a connect bug for it.

Comment: Hello Kin, I updated my answer. I read through your answer again and noticed some steps I hadn't considered such as recompile and refreshing views. Do these still apply in 2016? I did also try the ALL option for UpdateStatistics and the @MSShippedObjects='Y' which doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: @CraigEfrein the reason you dont see any difference is because the tables you have mentioned are [system base tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503.aspx) which are accessible only using DAC connection.

Comment: @CraigEfrein and Kin: the reason that setting `@MSShippedObjects='Y', @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'` did not help is simply due to Ola's script filtering out system tables via `WHERE objects.[type] IN('U','V')`. So you _could_ alter Ola's script to include `S` as well, but I don't recommend that. DMason's [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/146054/30859) would work.