# SQL server migration to new server from 2008 R2 to SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, migration

I need to run the upgrade advisor before migration, so my question is where to Run the upgrade advisor ? In the old server or after restoring the DB in new server ?

As I am new to migration so need help and what all things I should take care for Migration and step by step process would be helpful.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information.  You will run the upgrade advisor on the new server after you restore the old database to it and it upgrades it.  This won't change your DB Engine level though. Please update with all the info that would be helpful, such as what the acceptable downtime is, what the acceptable data loss is, if we have a maintenance window, what the app is used for, how many databases there are, etc.  Otherwise this is a simple google search for "SQL Upgrade checklist".  Thomas LaRock has a pretty thorough one but it won't help you with the actual failover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [upgrade advisor 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256(v=sql.120).aspx) on a backup of your current to-be-migrated database which in your case is sql server 2008R2.

I have written [detailed steps on migration here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50315/8783).

PowerShell based [start-sqlmigration](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Start-DbaMigration) is what **I highly recommend** (I am using it quiet often to migrate server instances to new server) when you have to migrate your entire server instance.

e.g.

> Start-SqlMigration -Source sql2008R2 -Destination sql2014 -BackupRestore -NetworkShare \nas\sql\migration

*Make sure that the sql server service account has proper permissions on the NetworkShare*

[image]